# Storing closure functions within array using loop

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

This is the code :

> i'm storing the function body inside each element of "**resultArr**"
>   , the problem is when i call the stored function `_class[0]()`i can't reach the exact `i` it's always 4 !

```
var checkAttendanceFunc = function(nameArr) {
  var resultArr = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < nameArr.length; i++) {
    resultArr.push(function(){console.log('Is', nameArr[i], 'present?', i);});
  }
  return resultArrultArr;
};

var _class = checkAttendanceFunc(["alex", "brownex", "chris", "mack"]);
```

i think it's obvious if i call any item of _class i.e `_class[0]()` the index will be 4 and the name will be "undefined"

So how wan i solve this problem, i saw some ppl use the apply native function, but i think it works only if we store the function name not the body of a given function

Comment: How do you plan to eventually use `resultArr` The intent of this code isn't quite clear... e.g., it looks like you're using `i` as a flag for presence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, all the closures inside `checkAttendanceFunc` point to a **reference** of the `i` and `nameArr` variable.

When the loop is done, `i`'s value is 4 **for all the functions you generated**, what you need is copying `i` each time you pass it to a closure.

There are several ways for you to achieve this:

#### Immediately call the function

```
var checkAttendanceFunc = function(nameArr) {
  var resultArr = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < nameArr.length; i++) {
    resultArr.push(function(index){
        return function(){
            console.log('Is', nameArr[index], 'present?', index);
        }
    }(i));
  }
  return resultArr;
};
```

Here you're passing an argument fo the closure and you call it immediately. In this case, `i` is getting **copied** and the function has its own value named `index`.

#### Use another function that iterates on the array

In this case I'm using [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
var checkAttendanceFunc = function(nameArr) {
  var resultArr = [];
  
  nameArr.forEach(function (value, index){
     resultArr.push(function() {
        console.log('Is', value, 'present?', index); 
     }); 
  });
  return resultArr;
};
```

In this case the functions created recieve a copy of `value` and `index`, which means they will **always point to the same values**.

Comment: Thank you that's great, you may also like how @jmar777 solved this problem.
thank you guys that was so much informative !

Answer (score 2):

Still not sure I understand the intent of this code, but here's a working version that does what I *think* you're trying to do:

```
var students = ["alex", "brownex", "chris", "mack"];
var _class = students.map(function(name, i) {
    return function() {
        console.log('Is', name, 'present?', i);
    };
});
```

See it in action [here](http://jsbin.com/caleqacile/edit?js,console).

---

If you're really just looking for how to make it work with a `for-loop`, you could always capture it like this:

```
var checkAttendanceFunc = function(nameArr) {
    var resultArr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < nameArr.length; i++) {
        resultArr.push((function(idx) {
            return function() {
                console.log('Is', nameArr[idx], 'present?', idx);
            };
        })(i));
    }

    return resultArr;
};

var _class = checkAttendanceFunc(["alex", "brownex", "chris", "mack"]);
```

Similarly, you can also use `.bind()`:

```
var checkAttendanceFunc = function(nameArr) {
    var resultArr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < nameArr.length; i++) {
        resultArr.push((function(idx) {
            console.log('Is', nameArr[idx], 'present?', idx);
        }).bind(null, i));
    }

    return resultArr;
};

var _class = checkAttendanceFunc(["alex", "brownex", "chris", "mack"]);
```

Either way, I personally find the `.map()` solution much more elegant and readable.

Comment: thank you , this version will work, but the idea is to store the exact local value from checkAttendanceFunc. that's what i'm trying to do !

Comment: @CUZPAINIDSFN Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by storing the "exact local value". Can you show an example of what you want the result to be?

Comment: that's awesomethe second code is perfectly working, the third one also and i like how you use bind that's exactly what i want .
you said using `array.map` is so elegant i agree but the question was how can i access to i.
thank you you helped me!